# Python 3 prime number gen memory error. Int range is too large to handle

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes, large-data

I've been using this prime number generator and I've been getting a memory error when entering numbers greater than 2 billion. I'm not an experienced coder.

I tried using `yield` but it stops my count from being returned. I also tried `xrange` but I think that is now `range` in Python 3

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
class Solution(object):

   def countPrimes(self, n):
      """
      :type n: int
      
      :rtype: int
      """
 
      count = 0
      c1 = 0
      c2 = 0
      primes = [False for i in range(n+1)]
      e = 200
      a = 1
      b = 2
      
      for i in range(2,n//e):
          
             if primes[i] == False:
                c1+=1
                j = 2               
                while j*i<n:
                   primes[j*i] = True
                   j+=1
                        
                for f in range((n-i),(n-i)+1):
                   if primes[f] == False: 
                        
                        j = 2
                        if i + f == n:
                             #print(i)
                             count+=1
                        while j*f<n:
                             
                             primes[j*f] = True
                             
                             j+=1
          
      for x in range(1,e//2):
       
       for i in range((n//e)*a,n-((n//e)*(e-b))):
         if i > (n/e)*a and i < (n/e)*b:
             if primes[i] == False:
                c1+=1
                j = 2
                while j*i<n:
                   primes[j*i] = True
                   j+=1
                for f in range((n-i),(n-i)+1):
                   if primes[f] == False: 
                        
                        j = 2
                        if i + f == n:
                             print(i)                          
                             count+=1
                             
                        while j*f<n:
                             
                             primes[j*f] = True 
                             j+=1
       x+=1
       a+=1      
       b+=1
       
      for i in range((n//2),(n)):
           if primes[i] == False:
               c2+=1              
               j = 2
               while j*i<n:
                   primes[j*i] = True
                   j+=1
                  
      return count,c2
ob1 = Solution()
with open("coutput.txt", "a") as f:
    print("Test" , file = f)
    print("e = 2000" , file = f)
    print("2324522934 (3,2)" , file = f)
    print("Match,P1,P2", file = f)
    print(ob1.countPrimes(2324522934) , file=f)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time), file=f)
```

The error I'm getting is on line 15
`primes = [False for i in range(n+1)]`

Comment: Well, for 2 billion, `primes = [False for i in range(n+1)]` is going to allocate about 8 bytes per element, which adds up to 16GB of memory. I'm not sure what you could really do about that, except to not use a sieve of eratosthenes. You could approximate the number of primes using the [prime number theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/264547/32049). Or, if you used NumPy, you could allocate an array of type `np.uint8`, which would only be 1 byte per element, which would only take 2GB of memory.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How large numbers do you need to be able to handle?

Comment: @KellyBundy as much as I can push it

Comment: You really need to look at https://github.com/kimwalisch/primecount

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple sieve-based `countPrimes()` that avoids `range()` and handles 2,324,522,934:

```
import time

def countPrimes(n):
    count = 0

    if n < 2:
        return count

    count += 1

    if n < 3:
        return count

    # We're going to waste half this space so we could do better
    odd_primes = [True] * (n + 1)

    number = 3

    while number <= n:
        if odd_primes[number]:
            count += 1
            index = number * number

            while index <= n:
                odd_primes[index] = False
                index += number

        number += 2

    return count

start_time = time.time()

print(countPrimes(2_324_522_934))

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

It'll just take some time for an answer.

Comment: 2,324,522,934 takes 12 milliseconds with primecount, how long does this take?